# Spring security and Thymeleaf doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am using Spring 4 and Thymeleaf
In my index.xhtml page i wrote:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"
        layout:decorator="layouts/layout">

  <head>
      <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>
  <body>
....
  <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
      You are authorized user! Hi, <span sec:authentication="name">Username</span>
  </div>
  <div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
       You are NOT authorized user!
  </div>
...
</body></html>
```

As a result I see:

> You are authorized user! Hi, Username You are NOT authorized user!

i.e. Spring Security doesn't work

My build.gradle (some dependecies) are:

```
compile 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.2.RELEASE'
compile 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:2.1.1.RELEASE'
compile 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:1.2.3'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.0.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.0.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.0.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:3.2.0.RELEASE'
```

My spring-security.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Настройка хранилища безопасности -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder">
            </password-encoder>
            <jdbc-user-service id="jdbcUserService" data-source-ref="dataSource"
                               users-by-username-query="select login, password, is_enabled from users where login = ?"
                               authorities-by-username-query="select u.login, p.`name` 
                    from user_group_ref ug, permission_group_ref pg, users u, groups g, permissions p
                    where ug.user_id=u.id and ug.group_id=g.id and pg.group_id=g.id and pg.permission_id = p.id and u.login = ?"
                               group-authorities-by-username-query="select g.id, g.`name`, p.`name` 
                    from user_group_ref ug, permission_group_ref pg, users u, groups g, permissions p
                    where ug.user_id=u.id and ug.group_id=g.id and pg.group_id=g.id and pg.permission_id = p.id and u.login = ?"
                    />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <!-- URLs на которых сработает интерцептор безопасности (permitAll - разрешить вход всем (в т.ч. анонимным)-->
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access='permitAll'/>

        <!-- Настройка входа пользователя -->
        <form-login login-page="/account/signin" authentication-failure-url="/account/login/fail"
                    username-parameter="login"
                    password-parameter="password"/>

        <!-- Настройка выхода пользователя -->
        <logout logout-url="/account/logout" />

        <!-- Включает поддержку функции "Запомнить меня" -->
        <remember-me remember-me-parameter="remember_me" user-service-ref="jdbcUserService"/>
    </http>

    <!-- Если указать этот файл в authentication-provider выше, то юзеры будут храниться в этом файле -->
    <!--    <user-service id="userService"> -->
    <!--        <user name="alexssource" authorities="ROLE_USER" password="123" /> -->
    <!--    </user-service> -->

    <!-- Хеширование паролей -->
    <!-- 
        При создании юзера используется так:
        -> PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        -> String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
     -->
    <beans:bean id='bCryptPasswordEncoder' class='org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder'/>
</beans:beans>
```

Before, I used the Apache Tiles and for it all works well.
I don't understand why Spring Secury don't work with Thymeleaf.
Please, help!

Comment: Is thymeleaf working in general? Do you have other pages that don't have security and are working correctly?

Comment: Yes, my signin page (which has thymleaf tag) works correct

Comment: And also this index.xhtml page contains a thymleaf tags that works correctly

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with it...

Comment: I solved the problem.
I just didn't add the SpringSecurityDialect to my config.
Now my config looks as

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="thymeleafResolver" />
        <property name="additionalDialects">
            <set>
                <bean class="nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect" />
                <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

and works fine!
Thanks geoand for your help!

Comment: You should probably add that as an answer so future readers will see it without needing to read the comments

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem. 
I just didn't add the SpringSecurityDialect to my config. Now my config looks as

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine"> 
  <property name="templateResolver" ref="thymeleafResolver" /> 
  <property name="additionalDialects"> 
    <set> 
      <bean class="nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect" /> 
      <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/> 
    </set> 
  </property> 
</bean>
```

and works fine!

Answer (score 3):

```
    @Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){

    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);

    // add dialect spring security
    templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    return templateEngine;
}
```