# Use of sec:authorize to load javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm making a development using Spring MVC and thymeleaf. 
I'm trying to use sec:authorize to load javascript. In other words, I only want this script to load when the user is authenticated.
Here is code I'm trying to get to work:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"
        th:src="@{/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
        <script src="/js/submit.js"
        th:src="@{/js/submit.js}"></script>
        <script src="/js/url.js"
        th:src="@{/js/url.js}"></script>

        <!-- admin -->
        <script sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" src="/js/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.4.js"
        th:src="@{/js/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.4.js}"></script>
        <script sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" src="/js/admin.js"
        th:src="@{/js/admin.js}"></script>
```

These last 2 resources I'm trying to use sec:authorize to load but they seem to handle every time I load the page. Is this a valid way to use sec:authorize? Id it isn't, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is this helpful to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348341/spring-security-and-thymeleaf-doesnt-work - probably you're missing some thymeleaf configuration

Comment: Instead of using isAuthenticated() I used hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') as posted on the link you provided and it worked. Should I delete my question? (new on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isAuthenticated() may be returning ROLE_ANONYMOUS which is a legit role, hence why its returning true and rendering your script.

here is a good explanation why user can be authenticated by anonymous (which in turn breaks your logic) [Why is the 'anonymousUser' authenticated in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101738/why-is-the-anonymoususer-authenticated-in-spring-security)

To circumvent that and specifically advise you want user with specific access there is a need for roles such as ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, even though it worked I kept wondering why and this was very useful. The correct way to that would be:
        <script sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" src="/js/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.4.js"
        th:src="@{/js/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.4.js}"></script>